# text classification using weka in php

Tags: php

I am going to retrieve the posts from facebook and classify the words in the posts into different generic classes like vulgarity,hate,offense,politics,etc inorder to block them.
How to use WEKA tool for this purpose? I have used PHP for designing pages.

Answer (score 2):

You will first need to build a classification model. I presume that this part can be done using the standard Weka GUI. If you haven't used Weka before, you can read up the documentation and help here: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/

Once you have a model with you then it's upto to you how you'd want to interface it with your PHP scripts. Here are some options:

1. Use Weka's command line interface and use 'shell_exec' on PHP.
2. Using PHP and Java (since Weka's code is in Java): http://php.inspire.net.nz/manual/en/book.java.php
3. Other ideas such as Weka4Web etc. here: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~fracpete/downloads/#webweka

Comment: The second and thrid links are dead. Thank you for the answer @gat